# multiple in-app purchase in one app

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have  an  app with  multiple  in-app contents on same  page. when i buy one content it shows already purchased  even if i don't buy  all of them.

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
  {
     NSLog(@"[transactions count] : - %d ", [transactions count]);
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create multiple buttons for in App purchase ,then assign them different tags to identify them.
here is sample code:

```
- (void)purchaseProUpgrade{
    SKPayment *payment;
    if(btnTag ==0){
      payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:kInAppPurchaseProUpgradeProductId1];  
    }
    else if(btnTag ==1){
      payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:kInAppPurchaseProUpgradeProductId2];   
    }

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
} 

// saves a record of the transaction by storing the receipt to disk

-(void)recordTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction{  
   if(btnTag == 0){
            if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:kInAppPurchaseProUpgradeProductId1]){
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:transaction.transactionReceipt forKey:@"proUpgradeTransactionReceipt" ];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            }
    }
    else if(btnTag == 1){
        if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:kInAppPurchaseProUpgradeProductId2])
        {
            // save the transaction receipt to disk
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:transaction.transactionReceipt forKey:@"proUpgradeTransactionReceipt" ];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
    }

} 

-(void)finishTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction wasSuccessful:(BOOL)wasSuccessful{

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
   NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:transaction, @"transaction" , nil];
   if (wasSuccessful) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionSucceededNotification object:self userInfo:userInfo];
         if(btnTag == 0){
              //write ur code
         }
        else if(btnTag == 1){
             //write ur code
        }
}
    else
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionFailedNotification object:self userInfo:userInfo];
    }
}
```

this will solve your problem...

Answer (score 0):

please check this best tutorial of [Rey Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases) here describing full implementation of in-app Purchase with multiple products.